# PHP Xpath not returning all value

Tags: php, arrays, xpath, foreach

Kindly please help regarding Xpath...

Following scripts will scraping the main body of URL by using Xpath

```
<?php
//sentimen order
if (PHP_SAPI != 'cli') {
echo "<pre>";
}

require_once __DIR__ . '/../autoload.php';
$sentiment = new \PHPInsight\Sentiment();

require_once 'Xpath.php';


$startUrl = "http://news.sky.com/story/1445575/suspect-held-over-shooting-of-ferguson-police/";

$xpath = new XPATH($startUrl);

// We starts from the root element
$query = '/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/article/div/div[2]/div[2]/p[3]';


$strQuery = $xpath->query($query);
$strNode = $strQuery->item(0)->nodeValue;

$result = array($strNode);

foreach ($result as $string) {

// calculations:
$scores = $sentiment->score($string);
$class = $sentiment->categorise($string);

// output:
echo "Strings $string \n";
echo "Dominant: $class, scores: ";
print_r($scores);
echo "\n";
}
```

Above scripts run well except the array loop...Xpath does not scraping ALL content but ONLY the first line of main body..

I think the problem lies from array loop and foreach...

Anyone please help to fix this looping....

Answer (score 0):

You only fetch one paragraph. Additionally you only put one string into the array.

You're perhaps looking for something more along this lines:

```
foreach ($xpath->query('
//header/h1
|//header/p
|//header//p[@class="last-updated__text"]
|//div[@class="story__content"]/p') as $p) {
    echo string_normalize($p->textContent), "\n\n";
}

function string_normalize($string)
{
    return preg_replace('~\s+~u', ' ', trim($string));
}
```

Output:

> Shooting Of Ferguson Police: Suspect Charged
>
> A prosecutor says the 20-year-old suspect claims he fired the shots in a dispute with other individuals and did not aim at police.
>
> 05:19, UK, Monday 16 March 2015
>
> By Sky News US Team
>
> A suspect has been charged in connection with the shooting and wounding last week of two police officers in Ferguson, Missouri.
>
> St Louis County prosecutor Robert McCulloch told a news conference the accused was 20-year-old Jeffrey Williams.
>
> He said the suspect, a local resident, was facing two counts of assault in the first degree.
>
> Williams, who was arrested on Saturday night, is also charged with firing a handgun from a vehicle.
>
> "He has acknowledged his participation in firing the shots," Mr McCulloch told reporters.
>
> ...